# jQuery Select Failed To Change Input Value

Tags: php, jquery

I have this jquery inside PHP code :

```
echo '<select id="state" name="state" onchange="document.getElementById(\'state_text_content\').value=this.options[this.selectedIndex].text>
    '.$list_state.'
</select>
<input type="hidden" name="state_text" id="state_text_content" value="" />';
```

why onchange function doesn't update `#state_text_content` value? thank you.

Comment: You forgot to terminate a string in `onchange` attribute.

Comment: @lolbas : nice catch, bro... it works now! thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo '<select id="state" name="state" onchange="document.getElementById(\'state_text_content\').value=this.options[this.selectedIndex].text">
    '.$list_state.'
</select>
<input type="hidden" name="state_text" id="state_text_content" value="" />';
```

Without seeing everything, I think it's because you have a typo. There is a missing quote at the end of the onchange=""